# in MapboxGL How to get Current View of the Map with Markers and other all CustomHtmlElements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

Here I want to get current view of the Map into svg image string. In console log I am able to get the svg string. But after open it as image I am able to see only the Map. But Markers not show in the svg image. Suppose If I add customer html element or anything to the map I want to get all according to the current view. So how can I fix this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Capture Map View as SVG</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ABCD';

    // Create a map
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [12.550343, 55.665957],
      zoom: 8
    });

    // Wait for the map to load
    map.on('load', () => {
      // Create markers
      const marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([12.554729, 55.70651])
        .addTo(map);

      const marker2 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: 'black', rotation: 45 })
        .setLngLat([12.65147, 55.608166])
        .addTo(map);

      // Capture the view as an SVG string
      captureViewAsSvg();
    });

    // Function to capture the view as an SVG string
    function captureViewAsSvg() {
      map.once("render", () => {
        const canvas = map.getCanvas();

        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
          const svgElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
          svgElement.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
          svgElement.setAttribute('width', `${canvas.width}`);
          svgElement.setAttribute('height', `${canvas.height}`);

          const svgImage = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
          svgImage.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', img.src);
          svgImage.setAttribute('width', `${canvas.width}`);
          svgImage.setAttribute('height', `${canvas.height}`);
          svgElement.appendChild(svgImage);

          const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
          const svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svgElement);

          console.log(svgString);
        };

        img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      });

      map.triggerRepaint();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```